# Loading an X position between classes gives a "field is never assigned to" warning

Tags: c#, xna, warnings

So I created a small game in XNA and I am at the stage of coding AI. The problem I have currently is that I can't load the X position of the redNinja (player's character) and have the blueNinja (AI) read it and walk towards it.

Every time I try to reference it via redNinja.Position.X, it gives me the `field is never assigned to, and will always have it's default value null.` warning.

```
namespace Ninja_DM
{
class AI
{
    Texture2D blueNinja;
    Ninjas redNinja;
    float timer = 0f;
    float interval = 130f;
    int currentFrame = 0;
    int spriteSpeed = 2;
    int spriteWidth = 32;
    int spriteHeight = 28;
    public Rectangle sourceRect;
    Vector2 position_b;
    Vector2 origin;

    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position_b; }
        set { position_b = value; }
    }

    public Vector2 Origin
    {
        get { return origin; }
        set { origin = value; }
    }

    public Texture2D Texture
    {
        get { return blueNinja; }
        set { blueNinja = value; }
    }

    public Rectangle SourceRect
    {
        get { return sourceRect; }
        set { sourceRect = value; }
    }

    public AI(Texture2D texture, int currentFrame, int spriteWidth, int spriteHeight)
    {
        this.blueNinja = texture;
        this.currentFrame = currentFrame;
        this.spriteWidth = spriteWidth;
        this.spriteHeight = spriteHeight;
    }

    public void AIMovement(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        sourceRect = new Rectangle(30 * currentFrame, 0, 30, 37);

        if (position_b.X > redNinja.Position.X)
        {
            AnimateLeftAI(gameTime);
            if (position_b.X < 20)
            {
                position_b.X += spriteSpeed;
            }
        }

        if (position_b.X < redNinja.Position.X)
        {
            AnimateRightAI(gameTime);
            if (position_b.X < 1100)
            {
                position_b.X += spriteSpeed;
            }
        }

    }

    public void AnimateLeftAI(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;

            if (currentFrame > 4)
            {
                currentFrame = 3;
            }
            timer = 0f;
        }
    }

    public void AnimateRightAI(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;

            if (currentFrame > 4)
            {
                currentFrame = 3;
            }
            timer = 0f;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: My bad. I'm still beginning in coding. Anyways, are there any ways to fix it/dismiss the warning?

Comment: @user1998250 Either you want it to be populated with the default value, in which case doing so manually instead of relying on the compiler would improve readability, and make the error go away, or you actually expect it to be initialized at some point, in which case you're not doing that.

Comment: @user1998250: Just assign the field.

Comment: @SLaks I'm sorry for this comment sounding extremely redundant and stupid, but my main question was how would I go about assigning it? That's my main confusion here.

Comment: When you write `Ninjas redNinja;` inside your class, that creates a **field** of the class. The field will be `private` because you didn't give any access modifier (like `internal` or `public`). When the field is `private` it can only be used inside that same class, `AI`. Therefore it is easy for the compiler to keep track of every usage of the field. The compiler sees that nowhere do you say `redNinja = something;`. Therefore the field `redNinja` will always have its initial value, which is `null`. Then, `redNinja` is not a useful field. That's what the compiler tries to inform you.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to bring the player's ninja as an argument when calling AIMovement(), something like this:

```
public void AIMovement(GameTime gameTime, Ninjas playerNinja)
{
    sourceRect = new Rectangle(30 * currentFrame, 0, 30, 37);

    if (position_b.X > playerNinja.Position.X)
    {
        AnimateLeftAI(gameTime);
        if (position_b.X < 20)
        {
            position_b.X += spriteSpeed;
        }
    }

    if (position_b.X < playerNinja.Position.X)
    {
        AnimateRightAI(gameTime);
        if (position_b.X < 1100)
        {
            position_b.X += spriteSpeed;
        }
    }

}
```

Notice you really don't need to declare a field variable called `redNinja` anymore because you bring the Ninjas in that you are testing against as arguments/parameters of the method.

Comment: Well, I got it running! Now I just need to fix up the AI a bit and see what I can do about movement. Thanks so much!